# Electron & TypeScript (&electron-builder): "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: typescript, electron, electron-builder

I want to build an electron app with typescript using electron-builder. Building itself works, but starting the app.exe brings this error: "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

[image]

I guess something is wrong with my package.json or tsconfig.json. Tried everything I could find, same error. This are my current configurations:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "main": "./src/main.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json",
    "start": "npm run build && electron ./dist/main.js",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "dist:dir": "yarn dist --dir -c.compression=store -c.mac.identity=null"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.12.7",
    "electron": "^8.1.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.3.2",
    "tslint": "^5.19.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "node-rest-client": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "build": {......},
  "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },   
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ] 
}
```

Comment: Does not help I'm sorry.

The bug appears when its calling the first import in the main.ts:

import { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, Tray } from "electron";

Comment: As far as I can tell, TypeScript needs to be transpiled into JavaScript using it's tool, tsc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I divided the output directories: 
/out for the yarn start process
/dist for the yarn dist process

Don't forget to change all the paths in the ts files to the /out directory

Comment: Hello Bro, I had the same issue. can you please give me more instruction for this:  I divided the output directories: /out for the yarn start process /dist for the yarn dist process. Thank you.